# Creating a link with CakePHP and JQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying create a `$this->Html->link` inside a JQuery script. This link goes redirect to an action in my controller the problem is that I can not do this.

How could I do this ?

Trying this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax":{
            url: "<?php echo $this->Html->url("/Empresas/indexAjax.json");?>",
            dataSrc:""
        },
        "columns": [
            {"data": "Empresa.id"},
            {"data": "Empresa.nomeFantasia"},
            {"data": "Empresa.cnpj"},
            {"data": "Empresa.telefone1"},
            {"data": "Empresa.telefone2"},
            {"data": "Empresa.celular"},
            {"data": "Empresa.aberto"},
            {"data":null,
                "bSortable": false,
                "render": function(obj) {
                    return "<?php echo $this->Html->link('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i>',
                                                        array('action' => 'view', obj["Empresa"].id), 
                                                        array('title'=>'view', 'escape' => false)); ?>";

                    //return '<a href=/Project/Empresas/view/' + o["Empresa"].id + '>' + 'View' + '</a>';
                }
            }
        ]
    });   
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You have typos in this. You're trying to get property of `$obj["Empresa"]` with wrong operator. You can do what you want with the code below.

```
<?php $link = $this->Html->link('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i>',
                                ['action' => 'view', $obj["Empresa"]->id], 
                                ['title'=>'view', 'escapeTitle' => false)]); 
?>

return "<? echo $link; ?>";
```